# Eclipse Android Runtime Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime, runtime-error

Currently working on a Android application for delivery drivers. Its been working fine for months but now it suddenly force quits when 'submit' button is pressed.

Whilst debugging its given me all sorts of run time errors relating to the android library.

[image: Error Log]

When I go to the exact location each one says Source not found. Everything is there as it should be and I've reinstalled the SDK and been through every file location.

Please Help

Edit:

```
if(isOnline())
                {
                    PODCache.clearedfordeliveryjobs.add(etDespatch.getText().toString());
                    new runner().execute(al_kvp);   

                }
```

PODCache is another class this is the bit the above is referring too.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    // Run this
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PODCache Started", 10).show();
    RUNNING = true;
    try {
        clearedfordeliveryjobs = (ArrayList<String>) LocalPersistence
                .readObjectFromFile(this, UNBLOCKEDLIST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        clearedfordeliveryjobs = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using eclipse-> right click project-> android tools ->"fix project setup" -> clean & rebuild, or "add add support library" if you use it ?

Comment: post pickupActivity line 178.

Comment: @max4ever I tried that and it broke even more, wont even load the app now.

Comment: @PadmaKumar posted above

Comment: PODCache.clearedfordeliveryjobs.add(etDespatch.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

What is keypod.keyfort.net.PickUpActivity? Have you tried finding that class? That does not look like a standard Android to me.

Comment: That's one of my own classes, i know the location of that. But inside it refers to one of the below classes which it cannot find.

Comment: @JoshNaylor so you know the exact line that the NPE is occurring at in your PickUpActivity.  what else do you need to debug it?  the other lines are just the current call stack from android internals.